# Moment-generating function of a specific random variable

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I'm calcuting the moment generating function for the discrete random variable $X=\mathbb{N}$, assuming probability $p(n)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2^n n!}$. Then I get
$$
g(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{tn}}{2^n n!} \,\,\, t \in \mathbb{C}
$$

Now, is there a simple expression for the sum of the above series?

Comment: Try reworking the summand into something that looks like the exponential series term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed there is. This is $$e^{-\frac 12}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^t/2)^n}{n!} \\ = e^{-\frac 12} e^{e^t/2} \\ =e^{\frac{e^t-1}{2}}$$